# Auto Size of Video in Video.js

Tags: video.js

Auto Size of Video in Video.js

Using Video.js for playing video files but unable to find an option of auto-size.
So, how to set auto size of video player based on size of video.

Is there a way of setting video height and width dynamically with respect to

Code sample is given below.

In cshtml page:

```
     <div id="VideoPopUpPlayer" style="display:none">
        <div>         
<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="metadata"> 
                <source src="" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
        </div>
        <a class="closevideo" style="display:none;">X</a>
    </div>
```

Js code:

```
videojs("MY_VIDEO_1").ready(function () {

videojs("MY_VIDEO_1", { nativeControlsForTouch: false});           

var myPlayer = this;              
myPlayer.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: rowdata.ProxyFilePath });            
myPlayer.play();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**DO Like it so the video can be able to be responsive**
1: option object with responsive true.
2: video.js css auto responsive it by fluid class.

```js
// language: lang-js

this.options={
        autoplay: true,
        controls: true,
        responsive: true,
        preload: true,
        playbackRates: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
        html5: {
          hls: {
            // withCredentials: true,
            overrideNative: true,
          },
        },
        sources: [
          {
            // withCredentials: true,
            src: `test.m3u8`,
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
          },
        ],
        plugins: {
          qualityLevels: {},
        },
      }

this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options, () => {
      // Initialize the quality levels plugin
      // this.player.qualityLevels();
      this.player.log("onPlayerReady", this);
      console.log(this.player);
    });
```